# Input mismatch exception error?

Tags: java, constructor

I am writing this code:

We focus on three geometric shapes: Circle, Rectangle and Square. 
Each one of these shapes is a geometric shape, hence, these geometric shapes can have a parent class (geometricShape) that includes common features of these shapes.

At the same time, every geometric shape is a printable and comparable object, among other objects that can also be printable and comparable, hence, these shapes will inherit the printability and comparability from two interfaces: Printable and Comparable.

Finally, as the Square is a special case of the Rectangle, the Square will be extended from the Rectangle in our design.

My problem is getting the square to accept only one input value (The side) while it is supposed to be inheriting the properties of the rectangle (that accepts 2 input values, width and height)

I've tried using a no argument constructor and a super constructor in the Rectangle class but neither worked to solve this problem.

Is it possible that the problem has something to do with something other than the constructors?

code of rectangle class:

```
class Rectangle extends geometricShape {

     private double width, height;
     private double side;

     Rectangle(){
        super();
     }

     Rectangle (double side){
        this.side=side;
     }


     Rectangle(double width, double height) {
          super.setShapeName("Rectangle");
          this.width = width;
          this.height = height;
     }

    public void setSide(double side) {
        this.side = side;
    }

    public double getSide() {
        return side;
    }

    @Override
    public double gerPerimeter() {
        return 2 * (width + height);
    }


    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        return width * height;
    }

    public double getWidth() {
         return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(double width) {
         this.width = width;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
         return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(double height) {
          this.height = height;
    }
}
```

code of square:

```
class Square extends Rectangle {

     double side;

     Square(double side) {
          super.setShapeName("Square");
          this.side = side;
     }

     public double getside() {
           return side;
     }

     public void setside(double s) {
           side = s;
     }

}
```

This is the rest of the code (without the square and the rectangle)

```
             public class Inheritance {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int Select;
    double Value1, Value2;
    String s;
    geometricShape Shapes[] = new geometricShape[2];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        s = (i < 1) ? "first " : "second ";
        System.out.println("Choose the " + s + "shape type:\n" + "(1) for a circle\n" + "(2) for a rectangle\n" + "(*) for a square");         // "*" means any other number 

        Select = input.nextInt();

        switch (Select) {
            case 1:
                System.out.print("Enter the radius: ");
                Value1 = input.nextDouble();
                Shapes[i] = new Circle(Value1);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.print("Enter the width: ");
                Value1 = input.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("Enter the height: ");
                Value2 = input.nextDouble();
                Shapes[i] = new Rectangle(Value1, Value2);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.print("Enter the side length: ");
                Value1 = input.nextDouble();
                Shapes[i] = new Square(Value1);
                break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The larger shape is:");
    if (Shapes[0].isLargerThan(Shapes[1])) {
        Shapes[0].print();
    } else {
        Shapes[1].print();
    }
}

public Inheritance() {
}
```

}

interface Comparable {

```
public boolean isLargerThan(E obj);     // The method returns true if the self object is larger than obj } 

interface Printable {

    public void print();
    /* For simplicity, let this method prints "A " + object name        + "with area: " + shape area */ }

abstract class geometricShape implements Comparable<geometricShape>, Printable {

    private String shapeName;

    abstract public double gerPerimeter();

    abstract public double getArea();

    public String getShapeName() {
        return shapeName;
    }

    public void setShapeName(String Name) {
        shapeName = Name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLargerThan(geometricShape obj) {
        return this.getArea() > obj.getArea();
    }

    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("A " + this.getShapeName()
                + " with area: " + this.getArea());
    }
}

/*part 1*/
class Circle extends geometricShape {

    private double radius;

    Circle(double newRadius) {
        super.setShapeName("Circle");
        radius = newRadius;
    }

    @Override
    public double gerPerimeter() {
        return 2 * 3.14 * radius;
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        return 3.14 * radius * radius;
    }

    public void setradius(double r) {
        radius = r;
    }

    public double getradius() {
        return radius;
        }}
```

Comment: Could you please add in your code?

Comment: What is _side_ for?

Comment: Aside from the question "Finally, as the Square is a special case of the Rectangle, the Square will be extended from the Rectangle in our design." is bad decision. Lets say you have method which expects list of Rectangles and needs to set their `width = 2; height=3`. But since you consider Square as subtype of Rectangle it is possible for such list to also have square instance there. What do you think, how such square should "look like" after being processed by that method? Would that result be correct?

Comment: @Phsemo Too advanced question for this level. Let's hope OP remembers it someday.

Comment: geometricShape should be GeometricShape by Java conventions. You do not need "super." to invoke setShapeName.

Comment: @RubioRic You are probably right, but it is worth remembering this [explanation](http://cafe.elharo.com/programming/a-square-is-not-a-rectangle/#comment-436689) from Uncle Bob (author of S.O.L.I.D. acronym): "The class Square is not a square, it is a program that *represents* a square. The class Rectangle is not a rectangle, it is a program that *represents* a rectangle. And just as the two lawyers in a divorce case are not divorcing each other, the representatives of two geometric shapes do not share the relationships of those shapes".

Comment: @Pshemo Good quote

Comment: I am writing this comment to let everyone know that i am an idiot and was not aware of what i am writing as '*' stood for any other number and when i ran the program I would input an '*' instead of a number and whine about how it didn't work. Sorry for wasting your time guys

Answer (score 1):

The described issue with Square and Rectangle can be easily handled by passing a single (side) argument to the `Square` constructor and passing that argument twice (as both width and height) to the `Rectangle` constructor:

```
public class Square extends Rectangle {
    ...
    public Square (double side) {
        super (side, side);
    }
    ...
    public double getSide () {
        return getWidth (); // a Rectangle method
    }

    public void setside(double s) {
        setWidth(s); // a Rectangle method
        setHeight(s); // a Rectangle method
    }
    ...
}
```

Your `Square` class doesn't require the `side` instance variable. And your `Rectangle` class also doesn't require it (it has `width` and `height`).

Note, though, that this doesn't prevent the user of your class from setting the width and height of a `Square` to different values. In order to prevent that, you can override the `setWidth()` and `setHeight()` methods of the `Rectangle` class in the `Square` class. The behavior can be as follows: whenever you change the width of a `Square` (by calling `setWidth()`), its height is changed to the same value, and vice versa.

```
public class Square extends Rectangle {
    ...
    public Square (double side) {
        super (side, side);
    }
    ...
    public double getSide () {
        return getWidth (); // a Rectangle method
    }

    public void setside(double s) {
        super.setWidth(s);
        super.setHeight(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void setWidth(double w) {
        setSide(w);
    }

    @Override
    public void setHeight(double h) {
        setSide(h);
    }
    ...
}
```

P.S. this answer doesn't explain the exception you mentioned, simply because you didn't include the code that produces that exception.

Comment: Sorry, the code is too big but i will try to include it in the question

Comment: Sorry, the code is too big but i will try to include it in the question

Comment: @weeabootrash You have various problems in your code. Those that have pointed Eran AND an InputMismatchException. It may be caused by reading a double without setting the Locale. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34226345/inputmismatchexception-using-scannernextdouble-with-valid-values

Comment: Okay I will rewrite my code again in a more organized manner and will hopefully be able to figure out all the errors. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can design your classes like
`geometricShape` class having abstract method like `area()`,`perimeter()`
Sub classs for example `Rectangle` will have width, length fields and will override `area()` and `perimeter()`

Comment: Yes i have done that but i didn't want to include the whole code because it looked so messy, but i included it now so people understand my problem a little better